# How do I send REST request with the oauth parameters added in the URI (as input parameters)

Tags: rest, oauth, soapui

I have a specificaiton for a project that accesses a third party service -RESTfully and requires oAuth authentication. [It accepts only GET method, and no access token is required since I will be trying to access the protected resources using consumer key and consumer secret values along with the oauth parameters.]

I am using SoapUI-Pro 4.6.1 and tried sending a **GET** request with oauth parameters as authorization header using signpost method, **but my project accepts only when the oauth parameters are sent in the URL**.

So, when I generate **oauth signature, nonce and timestamp values manually** using  this link- http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html and update it in my request URL, it is working fine.

Sample URL: http://sample.com/content/?oauth_consumer_key=abc&**oauth_nonce**=FUINSzmeoDh&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&**oauth_timestamp**=1384436218&oauth_version=1.0&**oauth_signature**=ISAsa2LJt3tVhgCnbL/GQszcZbc=

Instead of this manual step, is there a way to generate oauth_signature, oauth_timestamp & oauth_nonce values automatically and then use it in the request URI as an input parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the version SoapUI Version 5.0.0 and above, you have an option to add query parameters.
On clicking the text box on parameters, we get a window with options to add parameters. Refer to the image.[image]